# Fibre vs Copper short Distance

Tags: layer1, cable, fiber, cabling, speed

I am thinking of running Fibre optic from one room to a Nearby ONT/Router, I currently have about 15-20 meters of Cat 6, With a Gigabit UFB internet plan. With a short distance of around 20 meters would there be a huge speed gap between Cat 6 and Fibre?

Comment: Also check out the minimum limits to fibre - but I recently ran into overloaded fibre receivers on a 5m fibre patch lead. The receiver maximum power was the same as the transmitter maximum power - but I got overload, I believe due to reflections.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

The equipment interfaces determine the speed, albeit the medium used may have restrictions on which interfaces it can be used. If you have 1 Gbps ethernet, it doesn't matter if it is copper or fiber, it will be 1 Gbps ethernet.

Properly installed and tested Category-6 cabling can even run 10 Gbps over a short distance. You cable vendor should have provided your company with the lists of the category tests and the results for each cable installed. If the cable passed all the Category-6 tests, you should have no problems running 1000BASE-T (1 Gbps ethernet on UTP).

Comment: I Have 1gb up/down plan just wanting to know If I would notice a difference in speed over 20 meters on cat 6 vs fibre?

Comment: As I explained, it is the equipment interfaces that determine the speed. If your equipment has 1 Gbps ethernet interfaces, then you get 1 Gbps.